# VECM model using R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, economics

Guys I am running a VECM to estimate the effect of exchange rate on exports. I have to run the same model for 10 different countries. Is there any easy way to do it all at once? Like creating a loop or something.

[image]

Comment: Of course there is! Show us the code to run the model for one country and give us an idea of your data structure and we can help you generalize it to multiple countries.

Comment: You may benefit from reading a little bit about the site norms and the R tag norms, e.g., [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make a reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.